# In SQL Management studio, what is the overhead of displaying the result of a SELECT statement?

Tags: t-sql, ssms, sqlperformance

When you perform a SELECT over a large table in SQL Management Studio by default, the result is displayed in a Grid table. As we can imagine, when the result set is million lines long, the data will be fed to that table widget that is displayed in SQL Management Studio.

- Will that have an impact on the execution duration of the query ?
- If so, is it possible to disable the displaying of the results of the query, to get a more realistic execution time of that query ?

UPDATE :

When I say display, I don't mean "Display ... Execution Plan" but the display of the data on the screen

Comment: EDIT : when I say display, I don't mean "Display ... Execution Plan" but the display of the data on the screen.

Comment: hit the "edit" link and add this to your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 3 ways to display resultset in management studio

- results to text
- results to grid
- results to file

you can choose option 1 and chk execution time and compare it with option 2 execution time.

Comment: Could you please detail how to switch between the 3 modes ?

Comment: @SkippyFastol next to actual execution plan button in toolbar you will find buttons for them

Comment: @SkippyFastol , if it was a correct answer you r looking for, then mark it as a answer :)